# How to find certain Hex values and Char() Values in a MySQL SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql, char, hex

Anyone know the syntax to search a MySQL table column by hex value or CHAR() value?  Do I have to use a LIKE or IN()?

Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM `myWordTable` WHERE `definition` LIKE 0xE28098;
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM `myWordTable` WHERE `definition` LIKE CHAR(128);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second one is close.

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `myWordTable` 
WHERE `definition` 
LIKE concat('%',CHAR(128),'%');
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first example consider pattern match '%' == 0x25

```
SELECT * 
FROM `myWordTable` 
WHERE `definition` 
LIKE 0x25E2809825;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to UNHEX() values you want to match on.

For example, finding all accented e's that were corrupted into 0xC3A9:

```
SELECT id, FirstName
FROM Person
WHERE FirstName
RLIKE UNHEX('c3a9');
```