# MySQL, Search for data containing hex character

Tags: mysql

I've got a table my_table with a varchar column col1. utf8

If I was looking for all rows containing the letter a in col1 (balloon, aardvark, etc) then I'd do:

```
select col1 
from my_table
where col1 like "%a%" -- But how search for special hex character?
```

But what should I put instead of "%a%" if I'm looking for a special hex character, in this case 0xFFFC?

(This is the character: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffc/index.htm)

Note that I am looking for a way to specify this character in the **WHERE** clause.  I've seen this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/hexadecimal-literals.html as well as Stackoverflow questions/answers that also use hex characters in the Select part. I need it in the WHERE clause. I have seen this [How to find certain Hex values and Char() Values in a MySQL SELECT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994821/how-to-find-certain-hex-values-and-char-values-in-a-mysql-select) but that uses char(128), but I haven't got an equivalent char number in my case.

Answer (score 3):

use: 0x61 == 'a'

```
select col1 
from my_table
where col1 LIKE concat('%',0x61,'%');
```

**Her is a Sample**

```
    CREATE TABLE `tmptable` (
      `image` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
      UNIQUE KEY `d` (`image`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `tmptable` (`image`)
VALUES
    ('äöüß');

> SELECT image,hex(image) FROM tmptable WHERE image LIKE concat ('%',0xC39F,'%');
+--------------+--------------------------+
| image        | hex(image)               |
+--------------+--------------------------+
| äöüß`´'      | C3A4C3B6C3BCC39F60C2B427 |
+--------------+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: This does not work for my character: concat('%', 0xFFFC,'%'); It does not find it, but I know it's there because I can find it it I select for all rows and then go through the data in Python  looking for the character.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10784431)

Comment: @Rohit Gupta, Sorry, i am not the hole day at the keyboard, but the Answer is correct. i have add a Sample to clarify it works.

Comment: But the OP says it does not work for his character.  Looking at it now, I think it might, so I have upvoted it.  I am not able to reverse the flag.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the existing answers did not work for me when searching for the character 0x0A in a MySQL 5.7 database.

Rather than using:

```
SELECT my_col FROM my_table WHERE my_col LIKE CONCAT('%', x'0A', '%');
```

I found that the following worked better in my case:

```
SELECT my_col FROM my_table WHERE HEX(my_col) LIKE '%0A%';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your 'select' as this:

select col1
from my_table
where col1 LIKE CONCAT('%',X'FFFC','%');

You can read how use hexadecimal, as you say, in documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/hexadecimal-literals.html
and using concat you use the character resolved.