# How delete these characters ß Ð by hexadecimal mysql

Tags: mysql

I try to remove theses characters ß Ð but I see the only way to remove only this characters is by hexadecimal I try use

```
DELETE FROM table
WHERE field like '%ß%'

DELETE FROM table
WHERE field LIKE CONCAT('%',CHAR(195,159),'%')
```

but dont work corretly and delete another rows more data without this symbol

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994821/how-to-find-certain-hex-values-and-char-values-in-a-mysql-select

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401771/how-can-i-find-non-ascii-characters-in-mysql

Comment: I try both tutorial but dont work

Comment: I don't exactly know why because I'm not good with regex, but it works: http://rextester.com/SPG31375.  Look at comments on the first answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401771/how-can-i-find-non-ascii-characters-in-mysql

Comment: What collation do you have set for your field?

Comment: utf8_general_ci